# iOS forces rounded corners and glare on inputs

Tags: css, ios, forms

iOS devices add a lot of annoying styles on form inputs, particularly on input[type=submit]. Shown below are the same simple search form on a desktop browser, and on an iPad.

Desktop:

[image: Desktop]

iPad:

[image: iPad]

The input[type=text] uses a CSS box shadow inset and I even specified -webkit-border-radius:none; which apparently gets overridden. The color and shape of my input[type=submit] button gets completely bastardized on the iPad. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: -webkit-appearance: none; Helps eliminates most problems, but it still doesn't eliminate the gap between the two elements or the rounded corners. So any help on that would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You specified `-webkit-border-radius:none;` did you specify `border-radius:none;` ?

Comment: Specifying `-webkit-appearance:none` and `-webkit-border-radius:0` did the trick on iOS for me!

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The version I had working is:

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

In some webkit browser versions, you may also be faced with the `border-radius` still being in place. Reset with the following:

```
input {
    -webkit-border-radius:0; 
    border-radius:0;
}
```

This can be extended to apply to all webkit styled `form` components such as `input`, `select`, `button` or `textarea`.

In reference to the original question, you wouldn't use the value 'none' when clearing any unit based css element.
Also be aware that this hides checkboxes in Chrome, so perhaps use something like `input[type=text]` or `input[type=submit], input[type=text]` or instead filter out those that don't use rounded corner settings such as `input:not([type=checkbox]), input:not([type=radio])`.

Comment: -webkit-appearance: none; Hides checkboxes in Chrome - not a valid solution!

Comment: -webkit-appearance: none; does the trick! (-webkit-border-radius not needed)

Comment: Good point - does depend on the browser version, I've found, so that's just in there for a failsafe. I'll edit the post for relevance.

Comment: input:not([type="checkbox"]) would be a better way to avoid the issue in Chrome? Although it wouldn't work in IE<=8 though, but then again, that's not what you're trying to fix.

Comment: Using `input:not([type=checkbox]), input:not([type=radio])` means that the style applies to all buttons on Safari, since every button satisfies one of those two conditions. Instead, I used `input[type=submit], input[type=text]`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, it doesn't apply to all input types, it is a filter on all inputs. By using `:not()` you're filtering out the ones that aren't checkboxes or radio buttons. What you've added by editing is saying that it doesn't filter it out which simply isn't true.

Answer (score 17):

You can get rid of some more webkits form, input, etc. styling with this:

```
input, textarea, select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: It would still need `border-radius: 0;` to reset completely, and don't want a border-radius. Else just set the `border-radius`.

Answer (score 3):

For the submit button don't use:

```
<input type="submit" class="yourstylehere" value="submit" />
```

Instead use the button tag:

```
<button type="submit" class="yourstylehere">Submit</button>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: FWIW, just had this issue on a project, and the iPad 1 I was testing on also added styles to `<button>` tags. So I think you're better off solving this with CSS directly.

Answer (score 1):

have a look to [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/)

There's a demo where you can test the form elements and see how they look like in ios.
There are multiple webkit oriented properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is the what I use in my projects

```
* { 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; 
}
a, article, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, img, section, span {
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
}
input, select, textarea { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    -webkit-border-radius:0; 
    border-radius: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also get this problem in some browsers if you have the following:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" type="button">Link</a>
```

instead of:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>
```

This can happen if you change your input element for an anker element and forget to change `type` to `role`.

I had this problem on both Chrome and Safari on my IPad.